# How to get the number of features of a shapefile?

Tags: python, shapefile

I want to get the number of features from a shapefile, but can't get it right.
Here the code:

```
import ogr

# Open the shapefile and get the first layer
datasource = ogr.Open("E:HP_Python/GeospatialDevelopmentByExampleWithPython/ExampleData/data/world_borders_simple.shp")

layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)

print("Number of features:{}".format(layer.GetFeatureCount()))
```

Here the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b694e03f871f> in <module>()
      2 # Open the shapefile and get the first layer
      3 datasource = ogr.Open("E:HP_Python/GeospatialDevelopmentByExampleWithPython/ExampleData/data/world_borders_simple.shp")
----> 4 layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)
      5 print("Number of features:{}".format(layer.GetFeatureCount()))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayerByIndex'
```

Comment: Your datasource is none object. Please check whether your path to shapefile is correct or not.

Comment: Hi Poojan, thank you very much for the clarification! I could see, that I needed to use backslash instead of forward slash for the right path!